# assign variable value to another value dynamically in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I am phrasing variables in shell script and expecting some value but shows another value, example shows as below:

```
export var_a_b="12345"
var_a="a"
var_b="b"
echo ${var_a_b} # Output: 12345 (shows properly)

new_var_a_b="var_${var_a}_${var_b}"
echo $new_var_a_b # Output: var_a_b (But I am expecting actual value of var_a_b i.e 12345)
```

Can someone help me on where I am placing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You need parameter indirection:

```
$ a=b
$ b=c
$ echo "${!a}" # c
```

Comment: Please don't answer common duplicates; instead, vote to close as duplicate.